# Adding text in between numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a footer using VBA.

I want my footer to look like this: "Page 2 of 11".
I have tried to code it but it keeps giving me "Page 211"

Is there a way to add a " of " without compromising the current code?

Thanks!

```
Sub ExtractContractA1()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objRange As Word.Range
    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim i As Long
    Dim f As Long

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'Set objWord = Application
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
    objDoc.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False

    For i = 1 To objDoc.Sections.Count
        With objDoc.Sections(i)    
            Set objRange = .Headers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range    
            objRange = "PRIVATE AND CONFIDENTIAL"    
            objRange.Font.Name = "Arial"    
            objRange.Font.Size = 11    
            objRange.Font.Bold = vbTrue    
            objRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter   
            Set objRange = Nothing

            For f = wdHeaderFooterPrimary To wdHeaderFooterFirstPage    
                Set objRange = .Footers(f).Range
                With objRange    
                    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

                    With .Font   
                        .Name = "Arial" 
                        .Size = 9
                        .Bold = vbFalse
                    End With

                    .Text = "Contract"   
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                End With

                Set objRange = .Footers(f).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
                With objRange
                    .Paragraphs.Add
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    Set myTable = .Tables.Add(objRange, 2, 1)
                End With
                With myTable
                    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Employee"
                    .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = " " & Chr(11) & " "
                    .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=395, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                    .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                End With

                VersionText = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$2")

                Set objRange = .Footers(f).Range.Paragraphs(6).Range
                With objRange
                    .Paragraphs.Add
                    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

                    With .Font
                        .Name = "Arial"
                        .Size = 9
                        .Bold = vbFalse
                    End With

                   .Text = VersionText & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & "Page "
                   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                   .Fields.Add Range:=objRange, _
                               Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
                               Text:="NUMPAGES \of", _
                               PreserveFormatting:=True
                   .Text = " of "
                   .Fields.Add Range:=objRange, _
                               Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
                               Text:="PAGE  \* Arabic ", _
                               PreserveFormatting:=True
                End With
            Next f
        End With
    Next i
End sub
```

Comment: That page number format already exists - can't it be called?

Comment: Why do you want this? There is already a footer feature in Excel: check "Print", "Page Setup", "Header/Footer".

Comment: i have to automate a document which includes the header and footer.  
i have tried it today again but i keep getting "Page of 110" instead of "Page 1 of 10"

Answer (score 0):

In `NUMPAGES \of` the "\of" isn't a valid switch. Word seems to ignore it. What you want to do it something like {PAGE *\Arabic } of { NUMPAGES *\Arabic } where the "of" is between the two fields.

The code below will roughly implement the above idea. Please adapt it for use in your project.

```
Sub AddFields()

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Selection.Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Rng, _
                              Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
                              Text:="PAGE  \* Arabic ", _
                              PreserveFormatting:=True
    Set Rng = Rng.Paragraphs(1).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Rng.InsertAfter " of "
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Rng, _
                              Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
                              Text:="NUMPAGES  \* Arabic ", _
                              PreserveFormatting:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes you are right, that is what i want to achieve. ignore the \of. it was a mistake on my part. I am wondering if there is a way to include the word 'of' in between the two .fields.add. I tried .typetext but it gives me an error.